# Htmlunit redirect does not work

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using version 2.28, I am having some issues trying to click a
button that redirects me twice to different URLs.

The result of the click method it is an UnexpectedPage ... (response
status code 200).

I tried to set:
webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

but I can't reach the page after. I have JavaScript enable.

this is a web written in PHP 
the button is currently doing this:

```
$.ajax({
url: '{{ action('LoanController@checkLoanProcessed') }}',
data: data,
type: 'POST',
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
if (data.status === true && data.processed === true)
{ 
  clearInterval(interval); window.location.href = data.redirect; }    
}
});
};
```

Any clue ?

HTML

```html
<script>var SITE_URL = 'https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/';</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var user_id = '49095';
var user_first_name = 'JUAN';
var duration_6 = "6 Months";
var duration_1 = '1 Year';
var duration_2 = '2 Years';
var duration_3 = '3 Years';
var duration_4 = '4 Years';

var duration_6_quota = '6 Quotas';
var duration_1_quota = '12 Quotas';
var duration_2_quota = '24 Quotas';
var duration_3_quota = '36 Quotas';
var duration_4_quota = '48 Quotas';

var quota_label = [];
quota_label['quota_0'] = '6 Monthly Quotas of:';
quota_label['quota_1'] = '12 Monthly Quotas of:';
quota_label['quota_2'] = '24 Monthly Quotas of:';
quota_label['quota_3'] ='36 Monthly Quotas of:';
quota_label['quota_4'] = '48 Monthly Quotas of:';
var borrower_page = true;
var lender_page = false;

</script>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                      <title>
                            TuTasa - Your Account                    </title>  



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/css/datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/css/app.css?1512484810">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/css/app2.css?1512484810">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/css/bootstrap-slider.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

  <script type="text/javascript">
   
            var CURRENCY_SYMBOL = '$U';
            var CURRENCY_THOUSAND_SEP = ',';
            var CURRENCY_DEC_POINT = '.';
            var THOUSAND_SEP = ',';
            var DEC_POINT = '.';
        
  </script> 

 

 </head>
 <body>                                  
                      
            <div id="wrap" class="container-fluid">
                                <div id="main" class="row clearfix">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 main">
                            <div class="container-fluid create-new-loan ">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body pl0 pr0">

            <div class="row bs-wizard" style="border-bottom:0;">
                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete">
                    <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                    <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">1</a>
                    <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">1. Personal</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step active"><!-- complete -->

                    <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                    <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">2</a>
                    <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">2. Income</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step disabled"><!-- complete -->

                    <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                    <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">3</a>
                    <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">3. Decision</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step disabled"><!-- active -->

                    <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                    <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">4</a>
                    <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">4. Money</div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <form method="POST" action="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/loan/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="BXLImooTL1DnEn4ouSi4uCJ1GG4fZawTdRkRzDtG">
            <input name="int" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="49095">
            <input name="type" type="hidden" value="borrower">
            <div class="panel panel-default hidden">
                <div class="panel-heading">Income</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="borrow_amount_min" value="10000.00"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="borrow_amount_max" value="200000.00"/>
                                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="education" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Education<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select class="form-control" id="education" name="education"><option value=""></option><option value="1">Primary</option><option value="2">Secondary</option><option value="3">University</option><option value="4" selected="selected">Post Graduate</option><option value="5">Other</option></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="income_type" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Means of Income<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="income_type" name="income_type"><option value=""></option><option value="1">Employee</option><option value="2">Businessman</option><option value="3">Independent Professional</option><option value="4">Pension</option><option value="5">Allowances</option><option value="6" selected="selected">Rent</option><option value="7">Unemployed</option></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="hidden income-employee income-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="company_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Company Name<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="company_name" type="text" value="" id="company_name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="job_title" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Job Title</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="job_title" type="text" value="" id="job_title">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="company_phone_no" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Company telephone number<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="company_phone_no" type="text" value="" id="company_phone_no">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="company_supervisor" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name of Supervisor<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="company_supervisor" type="text" value="" id="company_supervisor">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="job_duration" class="col-sm-4 control-label">How long have you been with this job?<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select class="form-control" id="job_duration" name="job_duration"><option value="6" selected="selected">Less then 6 months</option><option value="12">6 months to 1 year</option><option value="24">1 year to 2 years</option><option value="36">2 years to 3 years</option><option value="37">More than 3 years</option></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>           

                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="monthly_income" class="col-sm-4 control-label">What's your monthly net income?<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" name="monthly_income" type="text" value="350000" id="monthly_income">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="disclosure">Need to show proof of income</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="monthly_income_text" readonly="true" name="monthly_income_text" type="text" value="Trescientos cincuenta mil">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="proof_of_income" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Do you have proof of income?<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="proof_of_income" name="proof_of_income"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Yes" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option><option value="Maybe">Maybe</option></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="bank_account" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Do you have bank account under your name?<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="bank_account" name="bank_account"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Yes" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes, but I don&#039;t remember the details">Yes, but don&#039;t remember details</option></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="calculate_status" class="form-control" value="1" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="calculate" type="submit" value="How much can I borrow?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <input name="temp_amount" type="hidden" value="30000.0000">
            <input name="temp_duration" type="hidden" value="0">
                            <div class="panel panel-default loan_amt_duration">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Find below the maximum you can borrow based on the information provided.
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                       
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h3>
                                        Amount
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                                                
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 mt-15">
                                    <a class="amountSliderDecrease" href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus mr-15"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <input id="amount" name="amount" data-slider-id='amountSlider' data-slider-class="slider-long" type="text" data-slider-min="10000.00" data-slider-max="200000.00" data-slider-step="10000" data-slider-value="30000.0000"/>
                                    <a class="amountSliderIncrease" href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus ml-15"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 mt-15">
                                    <input id="amount-manual-loan" name="amount-manual" class="amount-manual text-center" min="10000.00" max="200000.00"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h3>
                                        Loan Duration
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 mt-15">
                                    <a class="durationSliderDecrease" href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus mr-15"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <input id="duration" name="duration" data-slider-id='durationSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"/>
                                    <a class="durationSliderIncrease" href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus ml-15"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="pt-40 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row totals">
                                <div id="borrower-data-url" data-url="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/borrower/repayment-calculate" class="hide"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-25 selected-result">                                                
                                    <span id="borrow_amount">$U 30,000</span>
                                    <span class="amt_label">Total Amount</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-25 selected-result">
                                    <span class="borrow_quota_display">$U 6,171</span>
                                    <span id="borrow_quota_label" class="amt_label">
                                        6 Monthly Quotas of:<sup>*</sup>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-25 selected-result">
                                    <span class="borrow_rate_display">30.84%</span>
                                    <span class="amt_label">Interest Rate</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-25">
                                    <button id="credit_score" onClick="void(0)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg col-sm-12" name="review" type="submit" value="Proceed to credit scoring">Proceed to credit scoring</button>
                                    <button id="credit_score" onClick="void(0)" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:15px;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg col-sm-12" name="back_to_income" type="submit" value="Back">Back</button>
                                </div>
                                <input name="borrow_quota" type="hidden" value="6171">
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                        </form>
    
        </div>
    </div>
        <p>*Representative APR  <span id="borrow_rate" class="borrow_rate borrow_rate_display">30.84</span>%. Terms subject to market conditions.</p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    if(false){
        $('input[name="calculate"]').click();
    }
    
    $('#monthly_income').inputmask('[999999999]', {"numericInput": true, "greedy": false, "placeholder": ""});

    $('#monthly_income').on('keyup', _.debounce(function(){
        monthlyIncomeText();
    }, 1000));
    
    _.each(['input[name="borrow_quota"]','#purpose','#education','#priority','#income_type','#company_name','#job_title','#company_phone_no','#company_supervisor','#job_duration','#businessman_org_name',
            '#businessman_org_phone','#businessman_ref','#indep_prof_industry','#indep_prof_ref','#indep_prof_ref_phone','#retired_prev_employer_name','#allow_grantor','#unemp_prev_employer_name',
            '#monthly_income','#proof_of_income','#bank_account','#repayment_likelihood','#calculate_status','#fast_track_code','#fast_track_code_status','#amount_payable_to'], function(input){
                $(input).change(function(){
                    var data = {};
                    if($('#amount').val()) data[btoa('amount')] = btoa($('#amount').val());
                    if($('#duration').val()) data[btoa('duration')] = btoa($('#duration').val());
                    if($('#borrow_rate').text()) data[btoa('rate')] = btoa($('#borrow_rate').text());
                    if($('input[name="borrow_quota"]').val()) data[btoa('quota')] = btoa($('input[name="borrow_quota"]').val());
                    if($('input[name="borrow_quota"]').val()) data[btoa('total')] = btoa($('#duration').val() ? 0.5 * 12 * $('input[name="borrow_quota"]').val() : $('#duration').val() * $('input[name="borrow_quota"]').val());
                    if($('#education').val()) data[btoa('education')] = btoa($('#education').val());
                    if($('#priority').val()) data[btoa('priority')] = btoa($('#priority').val());
                    if($('#income_type').val()) data[btoa('income_type')] = btoa($('#income_type').val());
                    if($('#monthly_income').val()) data[btoa('monthly_income')] = btoa($('#monthly_income').val());
                    if($('#proof_of_income').val()) data[btoa('proof_of_income')] = btoa($('#proof_of_income').val());
                    if($('#proof_of_income').val()) data[btoa('proof_of_income')] = btoa($('#proof_of_income').val());
                    if($('#bank_account').val()) data[btoa('bank_account')] = btoa($('#bank_account').val());
                    if(input.indexOf('#') != -1){
                        data[btoa(input.replace('#', ''))] = btoa($(input).val());
                    }
                    data[btoa('user_id')] = btoa(49095);
                    data[btoa('type')] = btoa('borrower');
                    data['_token'] = $('form').find('input[name="_token"]').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/loan/save-temp-loan',
                        data: data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json"
                    });
                });
            });

    $('#fast_track_code_status').val('');
    $('.fast_track_code_error').hide();
    if($('#fast_track_code').val() != '') {
        if($('#fast_track_code_apply').length > 0) {
            $( "#fast_track_code_apply" ).trigger( "click" );
        }
    }
        
    function showIncomeFields(){
        $('.income-employee').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-businessman').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-independent-professional').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-retired').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-allowances').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-rent').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-unemployed').addClass('hidden');
        $('.income-'+$('#income_type').val()).removeClass('hidden');
    }

    showIncomeFields();

    $('#income_type').change(function(){
        showIncomeFields();
    });
    
    function monthlyIncomeText(){
        console.log($('#monthly_income').val());
        if($('#monthly_income').length && $.isNumeric($('#monthly_income').val()) && $('#monthly_income').val() > 0){
            var data = {};
            data[btoa('number')] = btoa($('#monthly_income').val());
            data['_token'] = $('form').find('input[name="_token"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/borrower/numbers-to-words',
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.status === true) {
                        $('#monthly_income_text').val(data.text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + data.text.substr(1));
                    }else{
                        $('#monthly_income_text').val('');
                    }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    $('#monthly_income_text').val('');
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#monthly_income_text').val('');
        }
    }
    
    monthlyIncomeText();
    
    });
</script>
                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
           
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/pdf/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/layouts/js/heartcode-canvasloader-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/sliders.js?1512484810"></script>
<script src="https://staging.tutasa.com.uy/js/scripts.js?1512484810"></script>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to use a web proxy like Charles to capture what is going on on the wire. Another option is to enable HttpClient wire logging.
Compare with the thinks happen in real browsers. Provide more details and i will try to help you. Try to figure out what the content of the UnexpectedPage is.

Comment: @RBRi ticket updated with more information. I hope that helps to find the issue.

Comment: can you please add the html code of the button (including the onclick handler

Comment: @RBRi done, Do you need to see htmlunit code too ?

Comment: Please open a HtmlUnit ticket. If you page is public it will be helpful to add you java code. You code calls window.location.href but from an async ajax request. Please try to ignore the return code of the click event. After calling the click use webClient.waitFor... to wait some time and then get the current page from current window.

Comment: @RBRi I will open a ticket. I followed your comments:


creditScoreButton.click(); // ignore result
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
 LOG.info(((HtmlPage)webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage()).asText());

I am still getting a com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage